# Trusted Execution Environment Vs. Hypervisor or VMs: How are they related?

Tags: virtualization, tee

I am a newbie learning all about isolation and separation for securing applications and system software. In this regard, I was reading up on ARM TEE and how it is available on most Android phones to offer better security for important system encryption keys etc.

How does it compare with a bare metal VM where the hypervisor "maintains" strict separation of resources? Or should we think of TEE as a "hypervisor" for ARM architecture?